# Java HW, Adding 3 Ints to a LinkedList, only 1 is found via search method

Tags: java, linked-list, iteration

I have made a LinkedList of 3 integers. I am able to print out those ints via toString, how ever when I try to traverse the list and print out each int (getData()), it only prints out the first int and then stops because the next iteration points to null. I start at the head. Why does my head point to null during while loop?

main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    IntNode x = new IntNode(0, null);
    int z= 0;
    for (int i= 0; i <3; i++){
    System.out.println ("Enter an integer");
    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );    
    z=keyboard.nextInt();
    x.AddNodeAfter(z); 
}
    System.out.println (x);
```

here is my add method:

```
public void AddNodeAfter(int data){
    if(head==null){
    this.link= new IntNode(data, link);
    head=this.link;
    counter++;
    }
    else 
    {
    this.link= new IntNode(data, link);
    }
    counter++;
}
```

I also tried using an Add at beginning of list:

```
public void AddAtHead(int data) {

     IntNode node = new IntNode(data, link);
     node.setData(data);
     node.setLink(head);
     head=node;
     counter++;

}
```

Where I'm having a problem:

```
 public void deleteLast(){
  if (head==null){
      System.out.println("empty list");
    }
   IntNode current=head;
    while(current!=null){
        System.out.println("while loop data"+current.getData());
        current=current.getLink();

    }
```

I'm in the process of building a delete at end of list method, but cant get over this. The while loop only runs once and prints out fist int. Head is correct, but the it points to null, however there are more ints in the list. Console:

Enter an integer

1

Enter an integer

2

Enter an integer

3

IntNode [data=0, link=IntNode [data=3, link=IntNode [data=2, link=IntNode [data=1, ], ], ], head=IntNode [data=1, ], ]

while loop data

1

Comment: Your code is poorly formatted for this site making it hard to read, and I think that this may be due to your creating indentations with both tabs and with spaces. To fix this, use one or the other (myself, I like using 2-3 spaces for this site and no tabs). If your code is easier to read, it's easier to understand, and folks will greatly appreciate your effort to make our volunteer work easier to do. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Try to state an actual question in your post as well (note the use of "?" mark).  This also makes your post easier to read and address.

Comment: ugh,... now your code is all left-justified. I should have kept my mouth shut...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scanner keyboard = new Scanner( System.in );

should be outside the for loop.

this.link refers to object that invokes the method you need to modify the code a bit

```
 if(head==null){
            head=n;    // variable t should be Instance variable
            t=head;
            }
            else{
            t.next=n;
            t=t.next;
            }
```

the previous nodes next part should point to your current new node......